# Dynamic substrings of SET command in batch-file

Tags: batch-file, set, substring

I want a batch-file for testing substrings of SET command, like %var:~5,3%

See below:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set var=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
echo.
echo String: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
echo.
echo Samples of Substrings:
echo ~5,3   : %var:~5,3%
echo.~5 : %var:~5%
echo.~0,-2  : %var:~0,-2%
echo.
echo.Test more: (Type 000 for Exit command prompt)
:Loop
Set /P "SubStr=~"
echo.!var:~%SubStr%!
echo.
If %SubStr%==000 Exit
GoTo:Loop
```

output for input's user : ~5

```
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and output for input's user : ~5,2

```
var:~5,2
```

What is solution?

Thnx.

Comment: I use it in Windows XP. Maybe it's work fine in Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:Loop
Set /P "SubStr=~"
If "%SubStr%"=="000" Exit
echo(!var:~%SubStr%!
echo(
GoTo Loop
```